# Show search query used to find duplicate

Tags: feature-request, tags, duplicate-questions, edits

Google have an interesting feature in their support forums:

[image]

when you post a reference, the system will automatically show which query was used to find it.

Maybe this would be an interesting addition to the dupe-closing process on SO? I.e. when a question gets closed as a dupe, let the first closevoter specify the SO search query they used to find the original - with the default being the very last search query they made. (This would apply to SO searches only!)

[image]

It could be a gentle nudge to the OP to check the search next time, educating without being unfriendly.

Comment: What if we don't use search queries to find duplicates?

Comment: @Grace then none is shown. The most education is needed where people ask totally trivial stuff that is already canonically answered - those I think you usually do a quick search for.

Comment: Trivial stuff is usually the stuff that is pretty quick to find with `[tag] → FAQ` or just from memory, though. Or it's right in the Related column. I mean, I'm neutral with the concept here - it's a functional idea, though somewhat in-your-face. I just feel like I'll miss out, haha.

Comment: @Grace fair enough, it wouldn't work for those situations. It may be depend on users' habits: I rarely use the FAQ, and search a lot

Comment: @Grace It might however be possible to point out with a friendly message if the closed original was listed in the tag FAQ... but it might come across too unfriendly no matter how hard you try (It's hard to not make that sound like "You should have looked in the FAQ first, dumbass")